# Recursive list creation

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

I'm stuck on this issue with lists in SWI-prolog.
In Prolog a variable can be written once, so i can't deal with this problem.

```
check(Parameter, [H | T], Result) :- 
   get_res(Parameter, H, Res), 
   check(Res, T, Result).
```

So, predicate check/3 takes a parameter, a list and gives me the final result.
get_res/3 gives me a middle result i use as an input for the recursive case of check/3.
So in Result i must have Res for each recursive call.
I tried to use append([Parameter], [], Result) before the recursive call but the first time succeeds, then it fails because Result can't be rewritten.
I know i also need a base case, it may could be check(_, [], []). 
But I'm not even sure on that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For recursively appending your results to the output, you can modify the code as :

```
check(_,[],[]).
check(Parameter, [H | T], [Res|Result]) :- 
   get_res(Parameter, H, Res), 
   check(Res, T, Result).
```

Base case is also important in this situation to have a correctly working function. When you are calling check/3, make sure the argument for the `Result` is a variable s.t. this can work correctly.

Comment: I tried a similar solution  as yours previously, but i had named wrong a variable in the predicate get_res/3 that i didn' t show up there. I corrected it and with your implementations works perfectly. I have also added a cut after the recursive call. Thank you very much